# ContactSchema.Birthday for Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices is trhowing exception

Tags: c#, .net, office365, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am exporting the Contacts from Office365 using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices. I have the ContactSchema.Department property working but the same code is throwing exception for the ContactSchema.Birthday field.

The exception occurs in the line:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact.Birthday
```

The exception is something like *get_birthday() threw an exception*
[image]

I have the following code to get a contact:

```
Contact c = Contact.Bind(service, Items[i].Id, new  PropertySet(ContactSchema.Body, ContactSchema.Birthday));
```

Any idea of how we have to handle the Birthday field?

Answer (score 1):

That error means the property wasn't set on the Contact. Birthday is an optional property which means if it hasn't been set so no value with be returned. Because its a DateTime value it can't be null, while HasValue should also work to test for this some of plumbing in the EWS Managed API doesn't appear to work as it should. So what i would recommend testing for property first using TryGetProperty which will always work without throwing an exception eg.

```
        Object BirthDayValue = null;
        if (c.TryGetProperty(ContactSchema.Birthday,out BirthDayValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(BirthDayValue);
        }
```

Cheers
Glen